# Azure AD Graph API Manager of "Me" always null

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to read the Manager of the current account.

Below you see the code snipped of the function reading the "Me" object.
I've set the Manager in the Account in Azure AD and double checked.

The Manager Object is always null although I can view it in the Azure Management portal.

Has anybody a solution for the problem? Thanks.

```
    public async Task<Office365User> GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var currentUser = await this.Authentication.GetCurrentUser();

        var activeDirectoryClient = GetActiveDirectoryClient();

        var myAccount = await activeDirectoryClient.Me.ExecuteAsync();

        if(myAccount.Manager != null)
        {
            var managerAccount = await activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId(myAccount.Manager.ObjectId).ExecuteAsync();
            if(managerAccount != null)
            {
                currentUser.Manager = managerAccount.ToOffice365User(currentUser.TenantId);
            }
        }
        return currentUser;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `Expand(x=> x.Manager)` while getting user. It helped me when I was searching for manager of user with specified principal name.

I guess the following code snippet can be useful for you:

```
var user = (User) await activeDirectoryClient.Me
    .Expand(x => x.Manager)
    .ExecuteAsync();

var manager = user.Manager as User;
```